# Adding ActiveRecord's migration generators to a non-rails project

Tags: activerecord, migration, generator

Is it possible to get the Active Record migration generators that Rails has to work in a project that is not using Rails -- perhaps via rake tasks.

I have a Ruby project that is using ActiveRecord but it is not a Rails project.  So far, I create my migrations by hand which works but it would be nice to get the migration generators to work.  Is that practical?